# search and replace string in between "" after from tag

Tags: mysql, search, replace

I'm trying to update my `mySql` database. the value of `Value` is

```
{
    "Subject": "Subject here",
    "Content": "The content here",
    "TextContent": "Here text content goes",
    "To": "this is to user<to@example.com>",
    "From": "Name of User<from@example.com>"
}
```

Now what to do I've to search for `From` tag and then `Replace` the `Name of User<from@example.com>` to `other user<other@example.com>`.

The value after `From` tag is unknown for me. so i want to replace the whole things in between `""` quotes.

for that what I'm doing currently

```
UPDATE `Table_Name`
SET Value= REPLACE(Value,'Name of User<from@example.com>','other user<other@example.com>')
WHERE Name = 'Name_of_field' && INSTR(Value,'From')>0;
```

I know this is wrong way to do this. please suggest me a way because here I'm using `Name of User<from@example.com>` that is unknown for me.

Comment: I would explore search-and-replace using a regular expression. Have a look at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql and then if you need help with the regex I would post a new question just about that (tagged with 'regex')

Comment: @MartinWilson I'm going through that. I'm new to `mySql` so let me some time to understand that.

Comment: Is the order of fields (to, from, etc) always stays the same?

Comment: @peterm it may be or may not be. but if you can suggest something please do. in any scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it

```
UPDATE table1
   SET value = REPLACE(value, 
                       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(value, '"From": "', -1), '"', 1),
                       'other user<other@example.com>')
 WHERE ...
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b7e86/1)** demo

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you please explain it ?

Comment: This is working fine with demo, but it is not working with my data. it is inserting the data in begin of the `Value`

Comment: You're welcome. In short chained `SUBSTRING_INDEX` (first gets everything to right from `"From: "`, and then the second gets everything to the left from the next double quote) extracts the value of `from` field, which is then used in replace.

Comment: Show the data on which it's not working correctly, preferably in a form of sqlfiddle. You can change my sqlfiddle and post a new link here in  comments.

Comment: Good answer- simpler than using a regex (and UDF)

Comment: @kk12391 You didn't mention that you have backslashes in front of every double quotes which is **essential**. BTW why are you doing this??? Anyway see working sqlfiddle with your actual data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4395b/1.

Comment: Thank you man I've done that. replaced `"From": "` with `\"From\":\"` and `"` with `\"`. and Done. Thanks for the help you've done. Thank you so much. :)

Comment: You're very welcome. I'm glad it worked out for you :)